# Rails - Group by and Sum the Array of Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my rails app I'm retrieving the array of records with the following code:

```
Spree::Order.find_all_by_id([21, 20, 19, 18])
```

The structure of the Spree::Order is:

> Spree::Order(id: integer, number: string, item_total: decimal, total:
>   decimal, state: string, adjustment_total: decimal, credit_total:
>   decimal, user_id: integer, completed_at: datetime, store_id: integer,
>   bill_address_id: integer, ship_address_id: integer, email_address_id:
>   integer, payment_total: decimal, shipping_method_id: integer,
>   shipment_state: string, payment_state: string, email: string,
>   special_instructions: text, terms_of_service: integer, is_quick:
>   boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

I want the following result to be grouped by `created_at` and sum the `total` value.

That would be great if you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Grouped by `created_at` by year, month, day, hour, minute or second? You need to be more specific, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Spree::Order.select("sum(total)").group("date(created_at)").where(id: [21,20,19,18])
```